Highlight cell in a range if the cell value is same as the cell value in a column A
I am trying to write a VBA macro to highlight the cell (in a range) which has same cell value in column A.  I tried the code below, but it highlights all cell in columnA. I am stuck how to validate it against row and range. Any help would be appreciated.
I need to compare the cell values in ColumnA and highlight the cells which has same value in the range C:F in the same row.
If A1=A, then in the range C:F, cell with value "A" must be highlighted. If A2=D, then in the range C:F, cell with value "D" must be highlighted. Similarly this must check all values in columnA and highlight respect cell with same values in the range C:F.
ColA       ColC  ColD  ColE  ColF      

 A          A     B     C     D  
 D          A     B     C     D  
 B          A     B     C     D    
 B          A     B     C     D    
 C          A     B     C     D   


Sub ColorCellWithSameValue()

Dim R1 As Range
Set R1 = Range("C1:G20")

Dim R2 As Range
Set R2 = Range("J1:K20")

Dim fnd As Range

' search R2 for cell in R1
For Each cell In R1

    Set fnd = R2.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
        ' colour matched cells
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
        ' reset colour in unmatched cells
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
Next

End Sub


Is there a reason conditional formatting does not work in your case?

Conditional formatting was suggested to you on your previous question that was closed. Did you investigate that?

I am struggling to get the conditional formating. Any help would be appreciated. I prefer to have a VBA. Thanks

Option 1:

Collect all desired cells with a Range object
Apply highlight color on the desired cells all at once

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, hlColor As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, hlRng As Range
    hlColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            If arrData(i, j) = arrData(i, 1) Then
                If hlRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set hlRng = Cells(i, j)
                Else
                    Set hlRng = Application.Union(hlRng, Cells(i, j))
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    If Not hlRng Is Nothing Then
        hlRng.Interior.Color = hlColor
    End If
End Sub



Option 2:

Apply conditional format with VBA code

Sub Demo()
    Dim rngData As Range, hlColor As Long
    Dim oFC As FormatCondition
    hlColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rngData = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(1, 1)
    End With
    Set oFC = rngData.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=B2=$A2")
    oFC.SetFirstPriority
    oFC.StopIfTrue = False
    oFC.Interior.Color = hlColor
End Sub


Using conditional formatting like so:

Edit update: instructions for OP:
I applied this conditional formatting by selecting the cells B3:E7 and the rule details are as shown. Take care with where the dollars are in "=$A3"...
So, just select the cells you need.

I tried the conditional formatting as mentioned above, but it highlights sometimes and it does not. For cella value "A", it doesno t highlight. If i change it to some other values it highights. Also, it does not highlight the values in the range.

Works fine on the example I built from what you provided. If the cell contains a leading or trailing space then it will fail.
